# 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial' - Alicat

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

So I've installed alicat from github (https://github.com/numat/alicat) to try and control an alicat mass flow controller using my Raspberry Pi.

I've followed the instructions and have created the following program flow.py:

```
    from alicat import FlowController
    flow_controller = FlowController(port='/dev/ttyUSB0')
    print(flow_controller.get())
```

When I run this I get the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flow.py", line 2, in <module>
    flow_controller = FlowController(port='/dev/ttyUSB0')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alicat/serial.py", line 234, in __init__
    FlowMeter.__init__(self, port, address)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alicat/serial.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.connection = serial.Serial(port, 19200, timeout=1.0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

It seems to have installed correctly as alicat --help brings up the help file, pyserial is also installed.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: upgrade python version to `py3`

Comment: Magical - thank you! I thought I had done

Comment: glad that helped